# Calling a C# function by a HTML button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

What I’m trying to do is to call function by a button.

i'll leave you with a simple code **that doesn't work!**:

```
@{
    protected void print()
    { 
        @<p>WELCOME!</p>
    }
}


<form>
    <button  onclick="print" value="CLICK ME"/>
</form>
```

any idea on how to accomplish what im trying to do in the code above?

**NOTE: IM NOT USING MVC**

Comment: No. You can't do that. That's what JavaScript is for.

Comment: It wouldn't work if you wrere. `onclick` is for calling JavaScript functions..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't do it like this.It is not `ASP.NET WebForms`.

So if you want to Execute a C# function on Button click in Razor, you <strike>must</strike> could create a `Controller`,then when user clicks a button you <strike>must</strike> can call a javascript function and it sends an ajax request to your controller then get the data (if there is data) and display it.

Update: Here is an alternative simple sample about how to do this:

In your Controller Add this Method:

```
public ActionResult GetMessage()
    {
        string message = "Welcome";
        return new JsonResult {Data = message,JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
    }
```

And in your View (HTML):

```
<input type="button" onclick="GetMessage()" value="Get Message"/>
<p></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function GetMessage() {
        $.get("/Home/GetMessage", function (data) {
            $("p").html(data);
        });
    }
```

And don't forget to import jQuery library:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I assume your Controller name is HomeController, you must change the url if it has different name:

```
$.get("/{Controller-Name}/{Action-Name}", ...)
```

Comment: Edited to prevent creating assumption that MVC and Razor (syntax) requires MVC pattern. You can use Razor syntax and simply do standard HTTP POST to some other page, and/or same (mimicking a "postback" wherein you can "handle" POSTed data - more "bare metal" than "web forms", but same core concept)..Hth.

Comment: im sorry for being too dumb but how im supposed to make a controller in a asp.net website (without MVC) ?

Answer (score 35):

I know this is an old question, but this is the first result on google when you look up how to run an `OnClick` method in ASP Razor, and I think there is a better way to do this than the currently accepted answer. I don't know if this is new as of the writing of the original answer, but I do think it is the best way to handle this behavior because it doesn't require hand-writing of AJAX or JavaScript methods.

For those coming from Web Forms into ASP Razor, perhaps the best (and easiest) way to recreate that type of behavior is to use a Handler Method. Handler Methods are appended to the Get and Post methods, and can be run using forms generated by ASP Razor.

By default, your cshtml.cs page will have a function which looks like this:

```
public async Task OnPostAsync()
{
    <Do Post Stuff Here>
}
```

Sometimes though, you want to do something specific depending on what exactly caused the post. This is where you can implement Handler Methods.

```
public async Task OnPostButton()
{
    <Do button stuff here>
}
```

If you then want to use the button method, you simply create an ASP Button that indicates its handler method.

```
<form asp-page-handler="button" method="post">
   <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
</form>
```

This will tell razor pages to add a reference to the Button Handler Method in the querystring of the resulting button, like so.

```
<form method="post" action="/page?handler=button">
```

A visit to that will tell Razor to use the named handler method. As long as the name of the handler matches the name of the function and HTTP Method, it will run the function.

Your code would look like this:

```
@{
    protected void print()
    { 
        @<p>WELCOME!</p>
    }

    public async Task OnPostPrint()
    {
        print();
    }
}

<form asp-page-handler="Print" method="post">
   <button class="btn btn-default">CLICK ME</button>
</form>
```

Don't forget, this will only call the OnPostPrint method. If you need to run stuff every time you post, it needs to be in that method too. Probably best to break those tasks out into a separate function, and then call that from within the post methods. Makes it easier to maintain.

For more info on Method Handlers, including how to add variables to them, check out Mikes DotNetting! He did a great job of explaining this thoroughly, and I feel I learned a lot from his article.

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/308/razor-pages-understanding-handler-methods

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Even from skimming the article I can tell things generally line up with how I outlined my UI when dumping thoughts while too tired to write actual code. Using handler methods is a more intuitive approach for someone primarily accustomed to desktop development and that seems appropriate for something meant to be the spiritual successor to WebForms. :)

Comment: Thanks! I think it’s the most intuitive in general for mapping behaviors to specific buttons in ASP Razor, but different strokes for different folks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="click me" />

@{
    string MyFunction()
    {
        return "Hello Razor";
    }
}

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            var button = document.getElementById('button');
            button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                var test = "@MyFunction()";
                console.log(test);
             });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: if you want to use inline function you may want to define the functions like this:
@functions{
    string MyFunction()
    {
        return "Hello Razor";
    }
}