# cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object' web forms

Tags: c#, webforms

I have the following code in a ASP.NET Web Forms and I get an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

Code:

**C#**

```
protected void OnMenuItemClick()
{
   //...            
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="<%# OnMenuItemClick(); %>">Click this</a>
```

I saw many examples but none of them worked for me.

**EDIT**
This is a simulation of my actually code and since the html part is shared I cannot do much changes.
What I need is to call the C# method from the html but the tag must be **a**

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4537490/8967612) will help?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed it is a shared code and I cannot do much chnages

Comment: href expects a url and it seems like  OnMenuItemClick(); is void.  Try to return url from OnMenuItemClick()

Comment: @DeepakMishra how can I change to call the C# method but still as <a> tag?

Comment: You need to change the code of OnMenuItemClick()

Comment: @DeepakMishra it does not work, but the method can be also void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Href requires URL you need to send a URL string or URL.**

You can not call a void function here. Try something like this.

```
protected string OnMenuItemClick()
{
   // do something here...  
   return @"https://www.google.com.pk/";
}
```

**Html**

```
<a href="<%# OnMenuItemClick(); %>">Click this</a>
```

Comment: it does not work, I get an error "Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20766334/8490598 Have you tried it?

Comment: @Dino is it possible for you to remove semicolon `"<%# OnMenuItemClick() %>"`

Comment: @M.HamzaRajput stackoverflow example does not work since the method is not in a controller. I removed the semicolon and the error gone but the method is not called.

Comment: @Dino How do you know the method is not called, did you view source in html?