# ASP.NET core razor pages: <a> tag not performing whats written in it's @onclick

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, web, razor

So I have this line of code (pageName: Closet):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn" id="addText" onclick="AddPart()">Add Part</a>
```

and this is the addPart() function:

```
async Task AddPart()
{
    data_.Parts.Add(new CloPart());
    DataService.DB.Add(data_.Parts[data_.Parts.Count - 1]);

    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("handleAddPartButtonClick", DataService.DB[DataService.DB.Count - 1].PartName);
}
```

As I understand the AddPart() func will call a javascript function, this is that function:

```
function handleAddPartButtonClick(PartName) {
    // addText.innerHTML += "<p>\n${PartName}</p>"
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('ClosetUI164', 'AddPart()');
    console.log("linked correctly");
}
```

and i did include the  tag correctly with the correct path.

but still the javascript is not connected to the Closet page. Why do you think that is?

I tries way too many things and almost 6+ hours with chat gpt, but im new to razor web apps and its my first project on the topic without learning anything about it previously so im short on information here.

Comment: could it be because you wrote `addPart()` in the anchor tag but the method name is `AddPart()` (capital "A")?

Comment: Thanks for noticing but i already changed this forgot to update the content of the question. My bad.

Comment: so have u got any other ideas at why this might be happening?

Comment: Since you use `onclick="AddPart()"` ,how about `function AddPart()` ? Do you want to call a server-side event handler or ?

Comment: You can use `F12` to see if any error message in the console.

Answer (score 0):

> but still the javascript is not connected to the Closet page.

If you want to call the  Closet page, in asp.net core you can try:

```
<a asp-page="Closet" class="btn" id="addText" >Add Part</a>
```

Use View Source from a browser to examine the generated markup. A portion of the generated HTML is shown below:

```
 <a class="btn" id="addText" href="/Closet">Add Part</a>
```

If you want to use `onclick="AddPart()"` to call `function AddPart()` , you can try:

```
<a  class="btn" id="addText" onclick="AddPart()">Add Part</a>
<script>
    function AddPart() {
        alert("hello");
    }

</script>
```

If you want to call a server-side event handler ,you can use a named handler method in Razor Pages like:

in the cshtml:

```
<form asp-page-handler="AddPart" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Add Part</button>
</form>
```

In the cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddPart()
{
...//do your staff
    return RedirectToPage();
    
}
```

Besides, you can read [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-8.0)  and this link:[Asp.Net Razor Pages OnClick not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66025271/asp-net-razor-pages-onclick-not-firingto) know more.

Comment: Hi @Jack Smith, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?